# Replace complete HTML by mozilla addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to replace the complete HTML, and add additional javascript files with mozilla addon SDK?

With chrome it can be done by running the script at "document_start", stop the window and replace the complete HTML with an XHR response. I don't understand why is this so complicated, but I can live with that. As far as I understand the addon SDK has a page-mod module, which is about "running scripts in the context of web pages whose URL matches a given pattern." So in theory this should be done with the page-mod module, but I did not find any example which completely overrides the whole HTML. In theory the window.stop and replacing the complete HTML should work here too, but I am not able to access the addon (backend) files from the context of the webpage (frontend). By chrome this is done via "web_accessible_resources" in the manifest and chrome.extension.getURL. By firefox I cannot use anything related to the addon SDK by frontend, so self.data.url does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to send the file contents this way (since the addon file access was denied by firefox from the frontend):

index.js

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ["http://example.com/", "http://example.com/index.html"],
    contentScriptFile: "./inject.js",
    contentScriptWhen: "start",
    onAttach: function (worker){
        console.log("injector attached");
        worker.port.emit("inject", {
            "index.html": data.load("client/index.html"),
            "main.js": data.load("client/main.js")
        });
    }
});
```

inject.js

```
!function () {
    self.port.on("inject", function (files) {
        console.log("injector trigger");
        if (typeof hasRun == 'undefined') {
            console.log("injecting");
            hasRun = true;
            window.stop();
            var html = files["index.html"].replace("<script src=\"./main.js\"></script>", "<script>"+files["main.js"]+"</script>");
            document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
        }
    });
}();
```

If I replace the HTML with hello world, then it works. So the HTML appears to be invalid, but I got no error message and the console shows an empty HTML skeleton (I got an empty page). The same index.html and main.js code works by a chrome plugin, which I want to use in firefox. The only extra thing by the chrome plugin, that some js file is cancelled out, so they are surely not loaded before stopping the window. I tried to do the same, but maybe it did not work, I don't know.

index.js

```
let { Ci, Cu } = require('chrome');

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

var observer = {
    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([
        Ci.nsIObserver,
        Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference
    ]),

    observe: function (subject, topic, data) {
        if (topic == "http-on-opening-request" &&
            subject instanceof Ci.nsIHttpChannel) {
            var uri = subject.URI;
            if (uri.host == "example.com" && /some\.js/.test(uri.path))
                subject.cancel();
        }
    }
};

Services.obs.addObserver(observer, "http-on-opening-request", true);
```

The subject.cancel() runs by the some.js file. If I add logging:

```
            console.log("cancelling", uri.path);
            subject.cancel();
            console.log("cancelled");
```

Then the "cancelled" does not appear in the console, just the "cancelling, /some.js". I don't know whether this is normal, but I got no error message.

By trying this with a regular HTML webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
        !function (){
            window.stop();
            var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n</head>\n<body>\n  <script>console.log("loaded");</script>\ntext\n</body>\n</html>';
            document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
        }();
    //]]>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got an unterminated string literal syntax error, which is even funnier. I guess somehow the injector code does not work properly if it contains javascript, so this is not an addon related issue I think. If I use `<\/script>` then it is okay, but the `console.log("loaded");` script does not run. By chrome it does run, so that is the problem I think.

I added jquery to the "contentScriptFile" and used `$("html").html(html)` instead `document.documentElement.innerHTML = html`. It runs the scripts now, but still does not work properly.

Added some fix by cancel():

```
let { Ci, Cu, Cr } = require('chrome');
//...
subject.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
```

cancel appears to have a required status parameter, but it silently fails when it does not get it. Now cancelling files works too, but the plugin still fails somewhere. :S

I think the injector I wrote works perfectly, and the problem is with the injected HTML and js files. I don't intend to debug them (since $.load uses eval, so it would be very hard), I sent the code to the chrome plugin developers, maybe they can fix it somehow.